# SE reply intellisense, mouse only?

Tags: discussion, stackexchange

I'm stuck, at this moment, with Firefox 3.6, so I'm not sure this is what really happens.

When I reply to someone on StackExchange, and write @u(sername), an intellisense like tag appears, floating, just above the @u text with the 'username'. This is great, of course. However, and that's where my doubt is coming from, I'm not able to accept the suggested username by keyboard. I have to click on it.

Intellisense like systems accept either [tab] or [enter] as 'accept', and [esc] as 'cancel'.

The question is if you have noticed the same behavior in more modern browsers, and if this should be more keyboard oriented?

Comment: Shouldn't this be on meta.ux?

Comment: I have noticed the same problem, only a mouse click works. Also, no entry is selected by default, not even when there is only a single entry, otherwise [Enter] might work...

Comment: Thanks for migrating this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `[tab]`-key

<s>(This text is here to fulfill the minimum 30 chars rule)</s>

Comment: Cool, it works!